# Import .ACO color palette for Mac (for use with Keynote, Omnigraffle etc)

Tags: macos, keynote, color

I want to use my ACO color palettes from Photoshop to be available in Keynote, Omingraffle etc.

Is there any tool out there to export ACO files to whatever format that is needed to load that palette into Mac OSX system wide color palette?

Cannot find anything on the web that helps...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found at least two applications in the App Store that do this:

- The simple [Color Palette Importer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/color-palette-importer/id967592889?mt=12) (which worked perfectly for
  me) lets you import Adobe's aco files more or less directly into the OSX color picker.
- The more comprehensive (and more pricey) [ColorSchemer Studio](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/colorschemer-studio/id417896628?mt=12) lets you import palettes from a number of different formats, including Adobe's ase and aco, and exports palettes to, among oter formats, Apple's clr.

These two are just the ones I found, but there are tons of different apps for managing colors/palettes in the App Store, so there may be other apps there that can do the job, too.